# How do I dynamically update a feed with Flask and AJAX?

Tags: python, ajax, web, flask

I have created a system where some information is stored in a database and that information is then displayed on a webpage. This works fine but I want to add is a real time page updater that adds the new information on to the webpage without a refresh like Twitter does with new tweets.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Server Side Events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) which is designed specifically for this purpose and is more efficient compared to the AJAX implementation [(See this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397528/server-sent-events-vs-polling).