# Server-sent events SSE in PhP 7.4 - Apache hanging and not registering/serving any new requests

Tags: php, apache2, load, server-sent-events

**Context**

I am working on a **PhP Server-sent event application** running on **PhP 7.4 and Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 20.10**. The app does what it's supposed to, but, presumably, increased number of users (connections? SSE connections?) causes server to hang. I am expecting/would like to be able to handle a relatively large number of users (~1000), but my SSE events fire rarely (~3x in 15 min) and only look for and send a few string values found in a textual file on server.

**Problem**

My problem is that under some circumstances including increased number of clients (~70 to 100) **Apache starts hanging**. New HTTP requests are not reported in access log, no errors are reported in errors log, and any requests sent from browser seem to be loading forever with no server answer. **Server load (processor, RAM) in that moment is minimal** and I can access the server via SSH or FTP normally.

**What I've tried**

This happens with the default Apache configuration so following [online advice](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-http-with-mpm-event-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04) I tried **turning off mpm_prefork module** and **activating mpm_event and php7.4-fpm**. Not much changed except the number of clients going up for a few dozens but that also might not be true since I cannot test that manually, just have the application live-tested when I have a chance.

I've tried turning off the SSE element in the application and in that case I have no Apache hanging issues (but I can't update clients' info for which I need SSE). That means **SSE are probably causing an overload/Apache hang** with regard to something, but I don't know what.

I assume Apache hanging has to do with number of open connections or processes. As much as I've learned, I can control that only in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** (I tried setting **MaxKeepAliveRequests 0**) and in **/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf** (I tried setting **pm.max_children = 250, pm.start_servers = 10, pm.min_spare_servers = 5, pm.max_spare_servers = 15, pm.max_requests = 1000**) but to no avail.

**My questions**

- what can I do to **increase Apache supported number of connections/SSE processes** running?
- what can I do to find out **what causes Apache to hang** or what typically causes that?
- **any other ideas/suggestions** on how to solve Apache hanging?

My server-side code is

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
set_time_limit(0);

while (true) {
    
    if (configurationChanged()) {
        echo "data: " . newConfiguration() . "\n\n";
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        
    } else {
        sleep(3);  
    }
    
    if (connection_aborted()) break;
}
?>
```

My client code is

```
var source = new EventSource('myScript.php', {withCredentials: false});
    source.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log("Connection opened.");
    };
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
        // Do stuff with the obtained data here
    }
```

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: [This article](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-max-connections-apache/) suggests that by changing several of the options you have already tried, and a few others, can yield upto 8000 concurrent users.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Serverpilot helped my with this tutorial: https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-change-the-php-fpm-max_children-setting/#estimating-a-value ... In the server log file "php7.4-fpm-sp.log" I also have many entries of "script '/sse/index.php' executing executing too slow (5.753711 sec), logging". I have the while sleep set to 3 seconds. - I wonder if there is any other way not using a `while` to create SSE communication with the client. Maybe something like a "global cronjob" called every 3 s to avoid all the PHP processes on the server and thus the max_children issue.

Comment: See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75721983/1066234

Answer (score 1):

**The solution**

My main problem was I didn't expect Apache to hang while there were resources available on my server. A lack of experience caused me to waste many hours before I realized I should look for causes in

- Apache error log  /var/log/apache2/error.log
- FPM log /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log

I tried **re-configuring mpm-event module** according to [link](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-max-connections-apache/) given in the comment. While it helped to increase the number of concurrent users for a few dozens, the same **problem started occurring when number of users further increased**.

What did help was setting **pm = ondemand** in **/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf** to avoid having to manually defining parameters. I'm not sure why is that not a default or not more widely recommended. My problem seemed to be solved.

However, a new issue started occurring. FPM log /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log started reporting 2 kinds of errors:

1. **[mpm_event:error] ... AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.**
   which would leave my web application hanging for users for a few minutes, then going back to normal without any intervention.
2. **[proxy_fcgi:error] ... (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ... AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: ...**
   which would kill my web application for my users (so I added JavaScript to reload target php script to my users if the SSE connection ended)

**For 1.**
I tried to follow the error message instructions "Increase ServerLimit" and added "ServerLimit 250" to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.conf. That didn't solve the problem.
I found [this Apache bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555), but I was using a version where that should have been fixed. I then found [this page](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213901685--Websites-periodically-are-not-available-in-Plesk-scoreboard-is-full-not-at-MaxRequestWorkers) suggesting I should **change mpm-event to mpm-worker**. Worked like a charm and solved problem 1.

**For 2.**
Problem 2 was related to my PhP SSE application, in specific to the SSE script timeout. What did **NOT help was simply adding set_time_limit(0);** to my PhP script. Timeout was reached by proxy_fcgi according to the error, so I had to **edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf** and set
Timeout 3600
ProxyTimeout 3600

This increased any script max execution time to 1 hour (3600 seconds). This is not an ideal solution, but I haven't been able to find a solution to allow only particular script (in my case SSE PhP script running in an infinite loop) execution time.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: "**pm = dynamic** – the number of child processes is set dynamically based on the following directives: pm.max_children, pm.start_servers,pm.min_spare_servers, pm.max_spare_servers.
– 
**pm = ondemand** – the processes spawn on-demand (when requested, as opposed to dynamic, where pm.start_servers are started when the service is started.
–
**pm = static** – the number of child processes is fixed by pm.max_children." From https://haydenjames.io/php-fpm-tuning-using-pm-static-max-performance/