# Can Server-Sent-Events be implemented in PHP without a while loop (but a cronjob)?

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I am facing the same issue explained over here: [Server-sent events SSE in PhP 7.4 - Apache hanging and not registering/serving any new requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73970678/1066234)

That `max_children` of the Apache server are reached, due to numerous SSE connections of users.

SSE is created with PHP in using a while loop that is executed every x seonds. Example:

```
while (true) 
{
    if ($newevent) 
    {
        echo "data: ".$newevent."\n\n";
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
    }
    else 
    {
        sleep(3);  
    }
}
```

I started to wonder if there is any way (e.g. using a cronjob) to avoid the accumulation of PHP processes - and keep the socket connection open to be able to communicate. (Not websockets.)

Comment: Because PHP isn't the "server" (or the termination of HTTP), I'm fairly certain that the answer is "no". Something needs to listen on 80/443 for requests still. Although you could spinup another process somehow that might be more optimal, there isn't a way (that I know of) that you can "transfer" the request, short or creating a module/extension to the server.

Answer (score 2):

No. SSE (and web sockets) require one socket per connected client. When you are limited in the number of available sockets they are the wrong choice, and you should use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) and polling instead.

The advantage of SSE (push) over AJAX (pull) is the lower latency, because as soon as the data is available it is pushed to the client.

You can quantify the benefit. E.g. if you are polling every 5 seconds, and assuming 500ms of network latency, the data is available in the client after 500ms vs. an average of 3000ms (*). If you poll every 10 seconds it is 500ms vs. 5500ms.

The faster you poll the more requests per second reaching your server, and therefore the more load, so at some point SSE makes more sense.

Aside: AJAX *long* polling has the same pros/cons as SSE. By AJAX polling above I mean doing AJAX request using setInterval or setTimeout, creating a new connection each time, not keeping a socket open.

*: If you poll every 5 seconds, that adds between 0ms and 5000ms of latency, compared to data push, so the mean latency it adds is 2500ms. Then +500ms for the network latency (which you have for both data push and data pull) gives you 3000ms.

Comment: Sorry can you further explain the math in 500ms vs 3000ms / 5 seconds and 500 vs 5500ms / 10 seconds. I didn't get those numbers. lol

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize you give the mean of [0...5000], so it is n*(n+1)/2n.